# Difference between Chebyshev polynomial implementation in scipy and numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

Can anyone please tell me the difference between Chebyshev in numpy-

```
numpy.polynomial.Chebyshev.basis(deg)
```

and scipy interpretation of Chebyshev-

```
scipy.special.chebyt(deg)
```

It would be of great help.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `scipy.special` polynomial functions make use of `np.poly1d`, [which is outdated and error prone](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.polynomials.html#transition-notice) - in particular, it stores the index of `x0` in `poly.coeffs[-1]`

`numpy.polynomial.Chebyshev` store coefficients not only in a more sensible order, but keeps them in terms of their basis, which improves precision. You can convert using the `cast` method:

```
>>> from numpy.polynomial import Chebyshev, Polynomial

# note loss of precision
>>> sc_che = scipy.special.chebyt(4); sc_che
poly1d([  8.000000e+00,   0.000000e+00,  -8.000000e+00, 8.881784e-16,   1.000000e+00])

# using the numpy functions - note that the result is just in terms of basis 4
>>> np_che = Chebyshev.basis(4); np_che
Chebyshev([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.], [-1.,  1.], [-1.,  1.])

# converting to a standard polynomial - note that these store the
# coefficient of x^i in .coeffs[i] - so are reversed when compared to above
>>> Polynomial.cast(np_che)
Polynomial([ 1.,  0., -8.,  0.,  8.], [-1.,  1.], [-1.,  1.])
```